# Celery Process 'Worker' exited with 'exitcode 1'

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

**celery worker (part of Flask app) is getting killed before starting:**

Celery config parameters(Windows, Celery 3.1.25, Rabbitmq(latest))

```
flask_app = Flask(__name__)
flask_app.secret_key = 'some_secret'
flask_app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'] = 'amqp://localhost/'
flask_app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] = 'amqp://localhost/'

flask_app.config['CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT'] = ['json']
flask_app.config['CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER'] = 'json'
flask_app.config['CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER'] = 'json'
flask_app.config['CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT'] = True

flask_app.config['CELERY_ROUTES'] = {'task': {'queue': 'agent_queue'}}
flask_app.config['CELERY_IMPORTS'] = ['Monitor.app']
```

Outcome:

```
 -------------- celery-01 v3.1.25 (Cipater)
---- **** -----
--- * ***  * -- Windows-7-SP1
-- * - **** ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         MonitorSetup.app:0x4aad030
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     amqp://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ----
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . Monitor.app.task

[2017-12-12 11:39:08,266: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2017-12-12 11:39:08,390: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2017-12-12 11:39:09,496: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2017-12-12 11:39:09,526: WARNING/MainProcess] celery-01 ready.
[2017-12-12 11:39:11,930: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-4' pid:15512 exited with 'exitcode 1'
[2017-12-12 11:39:11,930: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-3' pid:11704 exited with 'exitcode 1'
[2017-12-12 11:39:11,931: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-2' pid:18656 exited with 'exitcode 1'
[2017-12-12 11:39:11,931: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-1' pid:6060 exited with 'exitcode 1'
[2017-12-12 11:39:15,244: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-8' pid:13520 exited with 'exitcode 1'
[2017-12-12 11:39:15,246: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-7' pid:11880 exited with 'exitcode 1'
[2017-12-12 11:39:15,249: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-6' pid:9488 exited with 'exitcode 1'
[2017-12-12 11:39:15,250: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker-5' pid:11712 exited with 'exitcode 1'
```

Working with celery for quite some time, but never had those issues before

Comment: Which version of windows are you using? I have this working perfectly on Windows 7 but running the exact same code on Windows server 2008 causes this exact issue.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's because celery 3.1.25 comes bundled with billiard 3.3.

If you upgrade that package (to 3.5 at time of writing), the service should work again.

```
pip install --upgrade billiard
```